# Access of undefined property

Tags: actionscript-3

Im trying to zoom in a picture for android, here's the code:

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

photo1.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM, onZoom);

function onZoom1 (e:TransformGestureEvent):void
{
    photo1.scaleX *= (e.scaleX+e.scaleY)/2; 
    photo1.scaleY *= (e.scaleX+e.scaleY)/2; 
}
```

And i get an access of undefined property error of onZoom. I've checked the instance names and all are correct

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call a function "onZoom", but it does not exist. Name your function "onZoom", not "onZoom1".